# In R: Unicode Character 'ZERO WIDTH SPACE' (U+200B)

Tags: r, string, unicode, character, whitespace

In R, is it possible to use Unicode Character '`ZERO WIDTH SPACE`' (`U+200B`)?
It does not get output when it gets included into a string:

```
> "x\u00B1y"
[1] "x±y"

> "x\u200By"
[1] "x​y"
```

I've been looking for packages that support the Unicode Character '`ZERO WIDTH SPACE`' (`U+200B`), but I did not find any.

Comment: There _is_ the character `U+200B` in your string: `nchar("x\u200By")` as well as `stringi::stri_length( "x\u200By")` both return `[1] 3` …

Comment: I added [r] to your question to attract a wider audience.

Answer (score 0):

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_space):

> The zero-width space (​), abbreviated ZWSP, is a **non-printing** character used in computerized typesetting to indicate word boundaries to text-processing systems in scripts that do not use explicit spacing, or after characters (such as the slash) that are not followed by a visible space but after which there may nevertheless be a line break. [emphasis mine]

In other words, it *is* there, but it is *not printed*.

I tested the base R functions, as well as the [tidyverse](/questions/tagged/tidyverse) ones, and they all seem to support it. You can see its presence in strings in subtle and not-so-subtle ways:

```
s <- "x\u200By"

nchar(s) # [1] 3
substr(s, 2, 2) # [1] "​"
stringi::stri_escape_unicode(substr(s, 2, 2)) # [1] "\\u200b"
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much! It helps to understand the concept of non-printing character. I was actually looking for a printing space character and found \u2007 (equal to the width of one digit) in the following table: en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_character